# How to get an unflattened array of multiselect values and single inputs together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, coffeescript

I have some dynamically created filters on a web app's page where the filter "entry" is at times the combination of a few different inputs and the values for the collection are gathered into an array to send back to the server. If these were all just single inputs then an array of values would be easy to map over to the inputs on the backend, however when one or more is a `multiselect` with multiple options, a flattened array of values mixing the `multiselect`'s values and the individual input values isn't appropriate.

As an example: if I have two inputs for a given filter on a search control page, one being a *multiselect* and another being a *text* input, I would like to gather an array of two elements, the first being an array of selected values and the second as the value entered in the text input. So if in the first *multiselect* I select `"A", "B"` and the *text* input I enter `"Joe"` and the code below gathers the input values:

*Coffeescript:*

```
filters = []
$(@customFilterElements.selector).each ->
  filterName = $(@).find('.filter_entry .filter_name:input').val()
  filterValues = $(@).find('.filter_entry .filter_value:input').map(->
   if $(@).data('multiselect')
     $(@).find('option:selected').map(->
       $(@).val()
     ).get()
   else
     $(@).val()
  ).get()
  filters.push({name: filterName, value: filterValues})
```

*Javascript: (converted from above)*

```
var filters = [];

$(this.customFilterElements.selector).each(function() {
  var filterName, filterValues;
  filterName = $(this).find('.filter_entry .filter_name:input').val();
  filterValues = $(this).find('.filter_entry .filter_value:input').map(function() {
    if ($(this).data('multiselect')) {
      return $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get();
    } else {
      return $(this).val();
    }
  }).get();
  return filters.push({
    name: filterName,
    value: filterValues
  });
});
```

*Current result for `filterValues`:* `["A","B","Joe"]`

The above code ends up producing an array `["A","B","Joe"]` for `filterValues`.

I think this may be because the `.get()` is converting everything to a flattened array. I tried using `$.makeArray()` instead of `.get()` and I get the same results but perhaps I missed something.

*Desired result for `filterValues`:* `[["A","B"],"Joe"]`

What I am hoping to produce is `[["A","B"],"Joe"]` so it is clear that the first element (in this example) is a collection of selected values from a multiselect to the backend.

How can I adjust the above code to get the desired result (for any combination or ordering of multiselects and single inputs together) in a fairly elegant manner?
The code is intended to be applied to any dynamically created filter, so reusable instead of hardcoding to each filter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a full night's rest the answer came to me right away and it seems so obvious now - just need to wrap the `multiselect` in an array bracket after the `.get()`! - doh. Sometimes documenting the problem here forces a solution to bubble up or highlight what I was missing.

```
filters = []
$(@customFilterElements.selector).each ->
  filterName = $(@).find('.filter_entry .filter_name:input').val()
  filterValues = $(@).find('.filter_entry .filter_value:input').map(->
   if $(@).data('multiselect')
     [$(@).find('option:selected').map(->
       $(@).val()
     ).get()]
   else
     $(@).val()
  ).get()
  filters.push({name: filterName, value: filterValues})
```